# Fechar arquivo usado pelo visual basic .net

Tags: vb.net

Galera eu estou usando o seguinte código para pegar imagens de um diretório e colocar em uma ListView:

```
    For Each arquivos In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(caminho, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.png")
        Dim nome_arq As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(arquivos)
        imagem.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(arquivos))
        ListView1.LargeImageList = imagem
        ListView1.Items.Add(nome_arq, contador)
```

E eu queria usar o comando a baixo para excluir a imagem que estava aberta no ListView1

```
     My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(dicionario(posicao), 
                                        FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs,
                                        FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin,
                                        FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
```

O problema é que eu recebo a mensagem de erro dizendo que o arquivo já esta aberto e por isso não pode ser fechado.

Então a minha pergunta é como remover a imagem para eu poder exclui-la?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Método Image.FromFile mantem o arquivo aberto.
Você deverá fazer isso de outra forma. Você pode e muito melhorar o seu código, mas para resolver o seu problema, fiz como abaixo (baseado [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079428/unable-to-delete-image-after-opening-it-in-vb-net-app) resposta) e funcionou de boa:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private caminho As String = "C:\teste"

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim xx As Image
        Dim contador As Integer = 0
        ListView1.Clear()
        imagem.Images.Clear()
        For Each arquivos In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(caminho, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.png")

            Using str As Stream = File.OpenRead(arquivos)
                xx = Image.FromStream(str)
                imagem.Images.Add(xx)
            End Using

            ListView1.LargeImageList = imagem
            ListView1.Items.Add(arquivos, contador)
            contador += 1
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text,
                                        FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs,
                                        FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin,
                                        FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
        ListView1.Clear()
        Button1_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Foi mal pelo código to começando agora, mas esse código esta com um problema para min. O nome das imagens mudam mas as imagens continuam igual, fiz um teste com 3 imagens e o nome mudou mas eles ficaram com a mesma "capa".

Comment: Editei a resposta. O contador estava dentro do looping

Comment: Quando excluo por exemplo a primeira imagem, ela é excluída do pc, mas não do listview. O nome correspondente a imagem some, mas uma imagem diferente e apagada do listview.

Comment: Editei a resposta, vc precisa limpar o seu image e a listview.